# How to remove label of a directory and all its contents in clear case?

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management

I have applied a label to directory in clear case recursively. How can I remove all those labels?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest approach would be in command line, using [`cleartool rmlabel`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmlabel.htm)

```
 cleartool rmlabel -rec YOUR_LABEL yourDirectory
```

Note: this is for ClearCase V7.1+ only, not CC7.0.x or CCV6.x, and not for CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client)

With older ClearCase versions, you had to do (see [technote swg21126736](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=727&uid=swg21126736)):

```
# Unix syntax
cleartool find yourDirectory -version "lbtype(YOUR_LABEL)" -exec 'cleartool rmlabel YOUR_LABEL"$CLEARCASE_XPN"'

# Windows syntax
cleartool find yourDirectory -version "lbtype(YOUR_LABEL)" -exec "cleartool rmlabel YOUR_LABEL\"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

---

Note: you *could* remove a label using a GUI, but as described in [technote swg21146450](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146450), this is a file-by-file operation only!

[image: version tree with label] [image: Remove label]

(Not very practical if you have hundreds of elements -- files and directories -- to process...)

Comment: I am using clearcase 7.1.2.3.. The first answer would help me a lot.. Thank you..:)

Comment: cleartool rmlabel -rec YOUR_LABEL yourDirectory removes label from current versions of elements. Is it possible to remove a label from all versions of elements (not only currently visible)?

Comment: @sandrstar I suspect for that you could go as far as deleting the lbtype.